# How to SELECT data which equals either Type X or Type Y in a MySQL join?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, where-clause

I'm trying to complete a MySQL task which has the following 2 tables.

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES
(100,'Oliver','Jake','Fearon Rd','Morrisville',13408,'NY'),
(101,'Jack','Connor','Road 124','Visalia',93291,'CA'),
(102,'Harry','Callum','Worth Ave','California',20619,''),
(103,'Bella','Swan','Butler Rd','Morrisville',13408,'NY'),
(104,'Charlie','Kyle','Womack Rd','Sanford',27330,'NC'),
(105,'Jinnie','Reece','Boyer Ave','Hammonton',08037,'NJ'),
(107,'Jessica','Davies','Worth Ave','California',20619,'CA'),
(108,'Isabella','Brown','Hawkins Ave','Sanford',27330,'NC');

INSERT INTO ENROLLS VALUES
(100,'CSC11',1),
(100,'CSC11',2),
(101,'CSC11',1),
(101,'CSC12',1),
(101,'CSC13',1),
(102,'CSC12',1),
(103,'CSC12',1),
(104,'CSC13',1),
(105,'CSC12',1),
(105,'CSC13',1),
(105,'CSC14',1),
(106,'CSC14',1),
(107,'CSC14',1),
(108,'CSC14',1);
```

> Retrieve information (SSN, first name, and last name) about students who are enrolled in the course of ‘CSC11’ or ‘CSC12’ (‘CSC11’ and ‘CSC12’ are course numbers).  Note: MySQL does not support “INTERSECT”.

According to the question  Students, 100,102,103 and 105 should have come as the answers. I've tried following gives the 101 also which includes both CSC11 and CSC12.

```
mysql> SELECT s.SSN, s.First_Name, s.Last_Name
    -> FROM STUDENT s
    -> JOIN ENROLLS e ON s.SSN= e.SSN
    -> WHERE (e.CourseNo = 'CSC11') OR (e.CourseNo = 'CSC12')
    -> GROUP BY e.SSN;

+-----+------------+-----------+
| SSN | First_Name | Last_Name |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| 100 | Oliver     | Jake      |
| 101 | Jack       | Connor    |
| 102 | Harry      | Callum    |
| 103 | Bella      | Swan      |
| 105 | Jinnie     | Reece     |
+-----+------------+-----------+
```

So kindly explain to me the mistake I have made here and the correct query.

Comment: You forgot the CREATE TABLE statement

Answer (score 0):

Add a `HAVING` clause which asserts that one, but not both, course numbers be present:

```
SELECT s.SSN, s.First_Name, s.Last_Name
FROM STUDENT s
INNER JOIN ENROLLS e ON s.SSN = e.SSN
WHERE e.CourseNo IN ('CSC11', 'CSC12')
GROUP BY e.SSN
HAVING MIN(e.CourseNo) = MAX(e.CourseNo);
```

### Demo

Note: The above assumes that `SSN` is a primary key in the student table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response. But this gives the answer as 101. According to the question we need answers except 101 that means all the students who enrolled in one of the mentioned course, not both.

Comment: @NawodaDharmabandu Check the updated answer, which now returns only students who have one, and only one, matching course of the two courses.

Comment: @NawodaDharmabandu, Student `102` will not come as it is missing in your sample `student` table. Add the entry in student table and then it will appear in the result.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have a small doubt here. Can't we use `XOR` ?. I believe `MySQL` supports `XOR`. I actually tried the same query with `XOR` and it didn't give me the expected result. Am i missing something?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy I have never even used XOR in a SQL query :-) ... XOR is a bitwise operation, and since we're not dealing with bit columns, it is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Ah Right ! :) But if you look at this example [MySQL XOR](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/mysql-xor-operator/) they are using it in Normal columns(at the end of the page) and that is why i got confused. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @ArunPalanisamythank you for your correction, I've corrected it in the question.Anyway, 102 is not coming as an answer.

Comment: The problem is that you forgot to enter student 102 into the `STUDENT` table.  Add it there, and my answer should work.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer sir, it gives the answer in dbfiddle but in my MySQL command line, it gives the answer without 102. can you give me a solution?

Comment: Check the above comment.